# Where is my visual studio 2010 xml editor toolbar?

Tags: xml, visual-studio-2010, xslt

I just got a refreshed laptop from our IT/department.  It has a very similar image as the old one.  I used to have the visual studio 2010 xml editor toolbar.  It is now missing and I do not see it in the selection of toolbars to add.  When I open an XML file it has the color highlighting that I expect but the XML menu just has create schema/schemas...

Does anyone know how I can get my XSL transform tools back?

Answer (score 2):

Right click on the toolbar and check "XML Editor"

Comment: THX for the answer but that's the problem.  Last item in the toolbar alphabetized list is Workflow.  No XML anything.